# Flash Builder will not read local JSON file . .

Tags: json, apache-flex, flash-builder

So I've tried to build a small utility to view the contents of a JSON file in an easy-to-understand manner (for non-tech people).

I have Googled far and wide, high and low, but every example that shows how to consume a JSON file in Flash Builder uses the HTTP service, pointing to a file on the web.

Here I am, sitting in front of my MacBook, wondering why I can't make this work. In the documentation I've found (sort of relating to this issue), they always show Windows examples, and they seem to work fine:

```
C://me/projects/json/my_json.json
```

Perhaps I'm completely missing the obvious, but is this possible on a Mac as well?

I've tried

```
file:///Users/me/projects/json/my_json.json
```

That doesn't work. I've tried some "resolve to path" syntax, but the HTTP service does not seem to allow for anything but file paths in quotes.

Would anyone be able to pint me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes. In the end I want it to be an AIR app.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) API. It's really easy, here's a quick code sample:

```
// Get a File reference, starting on the desktop.
// If you have a specific file you want to open you could do this:
// var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("myfile.json")
// Then skip directly to readFile()
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;

// Add a listener for when the user selects a file
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSelect);
// Add a listener for when the user cancels selecting a file
file.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onCancel);

// This will restrict the file open dialog such that you
// can only open .json files
var filter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("JSON Files", "*.json");

// Open the file browse dialog
file.browseForOpen("Open a file", [filter]);

// Select event handler
private function onSelect(e:Event):void
{
   // Remove listeners on e.currentTarget
   // ...

   // Cast to File
   var selectedFile:File = e.currentTarget as File;
   readFile(selectedFile);
}

private function onCancel(e:Event):void
{
    // Remove listeners on e.currentTarget
    // ...
}

private function readFile(file:File):void
{
   // Read file
   var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
   fs.open(selectedFile, FileMode.READ);
   var contents:String = fs.readUTFBytes(selectedFile.size);
   fs.close()

   // Parse your JSON for display or whatever you need it for
   parseJSON(contents);
}
```

You hinted at this in your post about examples being for Windows and you being on a Mac but I'll state it explicitly here: you should *always* use the File API because it is cross platform. This code will work equally well on Windows and Mac.